# XCode 4: some button titles not visible in iOS simulation

Tags: ios, xcode

I try to make a simple calculator using Xcode 4 for iPhone. It is my very first iOS application.

I use several buttons with titles: 1, 2,...9, +, =, -...
But when I run the program in iOS simulation, some of the buttons do not show their titles (i.e. they have nothing written on them).

The buttons without the titles are somewhat random: majorly the ones at the bottom of the screen, but also one on the top. The other buttons show their titles normally.

What the hell?

Comment: A picture and a relevant fragment of code would be nice...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same experience while doing the iOS calculator app from the iTunes U Piazza course. I think it started when I moved some of the buttons. I checked in the MainStoryboard.storyboard file with text edit - it appears that the height constraint went missing from these buttons - not clear how/why

whatever the root cause , I was able to fix it only by deleting the buttons in question and recreating them in the xcode editor

Answer (score 1):

Try simply copy and pasting the duff control - I had this problem after changing the view from inferred to retina 3.5

Comment: cut and paste worked like magic! - "poof" my button title has now reappeared!

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by turning off "AutoLayout" on the storyboard. more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16556044/26510

Answer (score 0):

Changing text type from attributed to plain worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Per Apple developer guide, you should not set either the button title label text or color directly as a property (for example, do **not** do this: myButton.titleLabel.text=@"SomeText" or myButton.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor]).

Rather, you set them using the UIButton setter functionality, like this:

```
    [myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

...or like this:

```
    [myButton setTitle:@"SomeText" forState:UIControlStateNormal];.
```

See [the Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html).

Answer (score 0):

I Figure it out that there are some reasons why this can happen. In my case the problem was that I was setting the background image as button image, so the text was right-shifted out of the bounds of the button.