# After xcode crash some buttons have either empty titles or are partially truncated

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

This seems to be a partial repost of [XCode 4: some button titles not visible in iOS simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759798/xcode-4-some-button-titles-not-visible-in-ios-simulation) but their question wasn't answered.

Please be gentle, I'm very new to this.

I've implemented a stack-based calculator program as per the stamford lecture series, but some of my buttons show as either empty or half truncated in the simulator. The same buttons will do it every time I run the sim, but if I move any buttons around it changes which ones are affected. It's usually the bottom ones.

First example here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDnoL.png - see how the bottom row of buttons don't display correctly? If I make any one of those buttons taller, it will show with no title but all the other four buttons will then show correctly.

I thought it might be too close to the bottom, or those buttons were broken, or similar. So I deleted the whole bottom row, made everything smaller, and then recreated those buttons and now I get four buttons with blank titles and two truncated: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsVW1.png

Note that the buttons all still work as expected, it's just the display that isn't right.

Am I doing something wrong? Any advice appreciated.

EDIT: Full code from the controller:

```
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorViewController()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CalculatorBrain *brain;
- (void)updateStackDisplay:(NSString *)value;
@end

@implementation CalculatorViewController

@synthesize display = _display;
@synthesize stackDisplay = _stackDisplay;
@synthesize userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = _userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;
@synthesize brain = _brain;

- (CalculatorBrain *)brain {
    if (!_brain) _brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
    return _brain;
}

- (void)updateStackDisplay:(NSString *)value {
    // if there's nothing sent so far, just initialise it
    if (self.stackDisplay.text.length == 0) {
        self.stackDisplay.text = value;
        return;
    }
    // This part is a little confusing. Extra assignment asked for = to be added to the end of the stack label if an operation was pressed.
    // Here I check for = at the end of the label and remove it so it's only displayed once. If "=" is being passed (done by the operation itself), it will be added back on right at the end of this function.
    if ([self.stackDisplay.text rangeOfString:@"="].location == (self.stackDisplay.text.length - 1)) {
        // .location starts at zero, .length doesn't.
        self.stackDisplay.text = [self.stackDisplay.text substringToIndex:[self.stackDisplay.text length]-1];
    }       
    // If we add a space after remove the = we'll end up with double space. Hence the else if, not if.
    else if (!self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) {
        self.stackDisplay.text = [self.stackDisplay.text stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    }
    self.stackDisplay.text = [self.stackDisplay.text stringByAppendingString:value];
}

- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *digit = sender.currentTitle;
    if ([digit isEqualToString:@"."]) {
        if ([self.display.text rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            if (!self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) digit = @"0.";
        }
    }
    [self updateStackDisplay:digit];
    if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) {
        self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
    }
    else {  
        self.display.text = digit;
        self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) [self enterPressed];
    [self updateStackDisplay:sender.currentTitle];
    [self updateStackDisplay:@"="];
    double result = [self.brain performOperation:sender.currentTitle];
    NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result];
    self.display.text = resultString;
}

- (IBAction)enterPressed {
    if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) {
        self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = NO;
    }
    [self.brain pushOperand:[self.display.text doubleValue]];
}

- (IBAction)clearPressed {
    self.stackDisplay.text = @"";
    [self.brain clearStack];
    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = NO;
    self.display.text = @"0";
}

@end
```

Comment: Looks to me like the internal UILabels of the buttons are being incorrectly positioned.  Are you messing with `UIButton.label`?

Comment: I don't think so, I've editted the entry to include the full controller code (sorry for the formatting)

Comment: OK, I'm not seeing it.  Perhaps you could [file a radar](https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/)?

Comment: Thanks CodaFi. I'll submit a bug report today. In the meantime, do you know how I can rectify this? Somebody told me that deleting the nib and starting again with the UI would do it, but it's storyboard and I don't know what the equivalent is for that. I was then told not to look for it because it's definitely not corruption. So I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: And this started since XCode crashed? (It seems you only say that in the title.)

Comment: And if you want to reply to a comment you usually 'tag' the user in your comment to make sure he/she gets a notification. 'Tagging' is done like this: `@[username]`, so to notify you (although that is not necessary, because you posted the question I'm commenting on you'll get a notification whatsoever): @JamesLawrie

Answer (score 0):

I got a maybe similar error, where some UIButtons had empty text, although by outputting titleLabel.text got the correct text value. I deleted the Buttons and added them identically to what it has before been in the storyboard. Then it worked.