# Stange behavior of xCode missing Text from the buttons

Tags: xcode4.5

I am experience a new and strange problem that I never experienced before. 
Text from the button are getting disappeared. I have already changed 2 buttons. now problem is started with third button. 
as in screenshot below :
[image: app and xCode preview]

Can anyone please help me if this is the strange behavior or I am doing something which I am not supposed to. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem after I moved some buttons into a scroll view. I tried a few things but the easiest was just to recreate the buttons.

Someone else had the same problem and that's the approach they took as well.

[XCode 4: some button titles not visible in iOS simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759798/xcode-4-some-button-titles-not-visible-in-ios-simulation/13589965#13589965)

Comment: Thanks Joe, Glad to know that that I am not the alone :)