# button not displaying correctly in iphone simulator in Xcode 4.6.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

My application view looks like this:

[image: view editor/storyboard]

But when I run simulator, it displays like this for some reason:

[image: simulator]

As you can see the three `UIButton`s in the last row are not displaying correctly. I am not sure what exactly is going on here.

What I am doing:

- I am creating an RPN calculator by following the CS193 Stanford iTunes U course. The buttons I am using are plain `UIButton`s, they are linked to the controller as `action`s.
- I am not creating these buttons through code, they are simply dragged into the view.
- I changed the text displaying on the button by double clicking on them. (I am not sure if this will help but I just provided this information in case it's helpful)
- It seems to be happening only to the buttons at the last row, since if I drag another button from the top to the bottom, the text will disappear as well.
- My thought: could it be related to the screen size difference of iPhone 5 and iPhone 4/4s? It seems that the storyboard gives me a screen of the size of an iPhone 5, but simulator is simulating an iPhone 4 sized screen.
- This was not happening before until I decided to resize the enter button to twice the size it is right now. After that happened, I resized enter button to it's original size, which is what is displaying in the pictures below, but that did not fix the problem.
- I tried changing the storyboard to 3.5 form factor, but that didn't fix the problem. (In fact, I tried all the combinations, including the ones that shouldn't work, i.e. 3.5 storyboard + 4inch retina simulator, etc.) and none of them is displaying correctly.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I am sorry but for people who are ***still*** down voting, would you mind read my question first? I already updated this post with all the information that I can give. The view is not built with code so I am not sure if I can provide any source code on the view part.

Comment: Your question does not contain any information giving a hint what could go wrong. Please consider providing more information, source code, whatever you are doing, ...

Comment: @Christoph Sorry about that, I thought this might be a common problem. I updated my post to include some information. Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: From where do you get the button titles? `.` and `..` doesn't ring bells?

Comment: @ott-- I set the button titles myself in the utilities settings on the right side of Xcode. Those are actually supposed to be "+/-", "del", "C" from left to right order, and it seems that they are cut off by something. I am not sure what `ring bells` mean? The compiler is not giving any warning, and the application runs completely fine. It's just the view is messed up.

Comment: Do you have _anything else_ in that same view?

Comment: @aqua No, I don't. This is what's puzzling me, since I don't have anything to overlap them with. Also I just realized that if I dis-align one of them, then that one will show up! I wonder if it's a bug in Xcode?

Comment: Maybe your buttons are outside the 'content' field for the view.

Comment: @aqua would you mind elaborate a little bit? I am new to ios development and I am not really sure how to check the `content` field for view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autolayout might be causing the problem. It's easy to find out: just turn off Autolayout in your xib/storyboard. Save, and build and run. If that fixes it, that was it.

(By the way, what we are seeing is clearly the *bottom* row of the text of those three buttons.)

Comment: To build on @matt's answer, a general rule of thumb is to not use Autolayout at this time as it's fairly new, and not supported by older iOS versions than 6.0

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! I was deeply puzzled by it. I wonder why apple turns this buggy feature on by default. Also what exactly does Autolayout do?

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_autolayout