# UIButton images look fine in IB but get stretched when displayed on app

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uibutton, uiimage

I'm developing an Enterprise app for tracking mileage and maintenance for company vehicles. I've added graphic buttons to snazz it up a bit. The buttons look the way they're supposed to look on the XIB in IB, and on the iPhone all other UIViews look correct, but on one particular UIView the graphic images are stretched way out of proportion vertically.

The first image below shows how it's supposed to look, with the three graphics buttons at the bottom. The second image shows how it's showing on the phone. The Help button on this screen cap shows normally, but it can't be counted on to stay that way.

It also is not consistent. Calling this view at any time may show the image stretched or it may not show an image at all. It rarely shows the image normally, like the Help button looks below.

The development phone is a 4S running 6.1.3. The views are set for the Retina 3.5 screen. XCode is the latest (whatever it is).

[image: The way it's supposed to look]

[image: The way it looks on the phone]

Again, it's only on this one view that the problem shows up. There is another UIView on the same view controller that is hidden when this UIView is shown. The button graphics on the other view look fine. All of the other views and view controllers use the same graphics on the UIButton, without any problem.

Comment: I don't suppose you're using autolayout for this app?

Comment: Are you using auto layout? If so, you might want to check out the constraints for those buttons to make sure they're correct.

Comment: Please post some code used for button, i think you are using constraints.

Comment: I found out where I can deselect Autolayout, and it is back to normal. I don't get how it got that way, especially since it wasn't enabled on any of the other view controllers. But I guess I clicked on something that, in my ignorance, shouldn't have.

Comment: Can anybody explain to this aging hippie why it did that?

Comment: Autolayout "on" is the default when you create a new xib/storyboard. Sad but true.

Comment: But I don't remember turning Autolayout "off" on the other XIBs, and they are all off. Is it possible that the Autolayout feature was added to XCode sometime _after_ I created the earlier XIBs? I've been working on this project for several months. I also don't understand why the activation of Autolayout would have the effect of distorting certain images, only on a certain UIView. Images were just fine on another UIView on the same view controller. _Sigh!_ There's so much to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to the comments here, I will answer my own question: I turned Autolayout off for this view controller, and that fixed everything. This is the first app I have written since XCode has begun development for the iPhone 5, so I wasn't aware of the Autolayout feature. I'll need to understand how it works and why it did what it did.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder (Xcode) you created the view using a 4.5-inch screen height.

But the device where you are seeing the problem is a 5-inch screen. So the view is resized to fit.

And when it does that, the autolayout constraints that Interface Builder put on those subviews take over to determine what *they* do. Those constraints are causing the heights to change.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552118/button-not-displaying-correctly-in-iphone-simulator-in-xcode-4-6-2 This problem particularly catches you unawares with respect to the last row of things in the window, for which Xcode automatically generates a very peculiar set of autolayout constraints.

Answer (score 1):

No need to turn Autolayout off. Autolayout can be very useful, but it seems to enjoy randomly assigning the constraint **"Align Baseline to:"** to UIButtons after repositioning them.

Just select the UIButton/UIImageView in question inside Storyboard, locate the constraint **"Align Baseline to:"**, tap the gear icon and select **"Promote to User Constraint"**, and tap once more and select **"Delete"**. This should solve your issue.